# Why is Feature layer not resolving DEBBaseMap given by NSW MapServer for javascript API 4.1.1?

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api, opendata

I have been trying to implement javascript API given by NSW for DEPBaseMap.
The layer can be added on  ArcGIS Online too and works fine with it, but doing same thing with the JS API, no map has been resolved. I think i have been missing something with the code in my javascript because other feature layers including NSW planning portal works goods for me.

```
        var map = new Map({
            basemap: "topo-vector"

        });

        var view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",
            map: map,
            center: [-118.27928, 34.13558],
            zoom: 18
        });

        var baseLayer= new FeatureLayer({
            url: "https://mapprod1.environment.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/Basemap/DPEBasemap/MapServer"
        });

        map.add(baseLayer);
```

The expected output should be like this[Expected outcome hyperlink](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmapprod1.environment.nsw.gov.au%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FBasemap%2FDPEBasemap%2FMapServer&source=sd)  [image: Expected outcome(Zoom out)]
[image: Expected outcome(Zoom in)]

This is what i have got with my code [image: my output(Zoom out)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url above points to a [*map service*](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/what-is-a-map-service.htm). So instead of adding it as a `FeatureLayer`, use a [`TileLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-TileLayer.html) and everything works as in the ArcGIS Online Map Viewer.

```
var baseLayer= new TileLayer({
    url: "https://mapprod1.environment.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/Basemap/OEHBasemapNPWSHillshade/MapServer"
});
map.add(baseLayer);
```

See the following CodePen for a live demo using the latest ArcGIS API for JavaScript:
https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/21dd5c26558b140fde4622862516cff4

Comment: <b> LEGEND </b> Appreciate your help. 
But I am still in confusion, I have been implementing all of the services it as a FeatureLayer and everything works fine except the DEBBaseMap . Can you please explain me a bit the reason for other  service to be some how working fine?

Comment: And yeah I have populated the  service layer  with the wrong URL , the URL to  DEBBaseMap is "https://mapprod1.environment.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/Basemap/DPEBasemap/MapServer" Any way it works and i owe you everything! 
Thank you @Arno